# R; How to find the 'most close' and 'smaller' vector// and see another vector on the same row?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the vector which is the most close to 0.5  but not bigger than that. And I want to print another vector on the same row.

For example, I have table named 'exp' like this

```
num  possibility
1     0.16
2     0.43
5     0.64
4     0.12
3     0.76
.
.
.
```

And I'm trying to find, 'which possibility is the most closest and smaller than 0.5?'.
The answer is second row, which contains 'num==2' 'possibility==0.43' 
But how can I find this with coding?

And I'm trying to calculate the '+-2' range of 'num' whose possibility is the most closest and smaller than '0.5'
 The num will surely be '5' and the range will be '3~7'.

But how can I do this at once with linked codes?

And whatif I have too many exp1, exp2, exp3, exp4... to do the same work? How can I automatically do this?

I tried things.

```
exp[which.min(exp$possibility-0.5 <0) -1 , 1]

x < exp[which.min(exp$possibility-0.5 <0) -1 , 1]+2
& x> exp[which.min(exp$possibility-0.5 <0) -1 , 1]-2
```

this is my best.
but I don't know why adding '<0' in the 'which.min' function makes difference, functioning like 'ifelse'. And how to find the 'closest smaller one' without using '-1' after 'which.min' function.

Actually I more want to know what are simpler and more useful tools.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you first expression (and similarly for the second one), when you do `exp$possibility-0.5 <0`, a boolean vector is what you get and what it is fed into `which.min` you are getting the min out of a bunch of one and zeros (True and False) which is not what you want.

> which possibility is the most closest and smaller than 0.5?

There are many ways to achieve, one is to set those larger than 0.5 to NA, first, which is done by the `ifelse`, then find the max probability with `which.max` like you mentioned:

```
exp$possibility[which.max(ifelse(exp$possibility> 0.5 exp$possibility> NA)),]
```

> And I'm trying to calculate the '+-2' range of 'num' whose possibility
>   is the most closest and smaller than '0.5' The num will surely be '5'
>   and the range will be '3~7'.

You can store the number in a variable first ...

```
my.num <- exp[which.max(ifelse(exp$possibility> 0.5, exp$possibility, NA)), "num"]
```

... and subsequently retrive it by

```
exp[exp$num >= (my.num -2) & exp$num <= (my.num + 2), ]
```

or put replace my.num with the first expression if you really want a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. you can basically set 3 to get variations. Also you could put this in a function and use lapply to iterate over all cols.

```
f=data.frame(a=seq(1:10), b=runif(10))
c=0.5
z=f$b-c
z=ifelse(z>0, 99, z) # add if you dont want values above 0.5
z=abs(z)
z1=order(z)[1:3]
f$b[z1]
```